# Поиск по комбинации символов в любом месте слова и строки с помощью ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Допустим, есть вот такой набор объектов:

```
{
  jobs:[{
    "jobTitle" : "йцуцй",
    "category" : "Дизайн",
    "jobType" : "Постоянная",
    "headOffice" : "qwe",
    "region" : "ewq",
    "tags" : "qwe",
    "applyLink" : "ewq",
  },
  {
    "jobTitle" : "ReactJS Developer",
    "category" : "Дизайн",
    "jobType" : "Contract",
    "headOffice" : "Moscow",
    "region" : "Moscow",
    "tags" : "Гейм-дизайн, левел-дизайн",
    "applyLink" : "sdfsdfds",
  }]
}
```

И допустим, есть слово поиска, например: "w"

И должно найти по полям:

```
[{
    "headOffice" : "qwe",
    "region" : "ewq",
    "tags" : "qwe",
    "applyLink" : "ewq",
},
{
    "headOffice" : "Moscow",
    "region" : "Moscow",
}]
```

Потому что там везде есть слово "w".

КОнфигурация для поиска не работает так как нужно.

```
{
        index: 'jobs',
        body: {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: keyword,
                    type: 'phrase_prefix',
                    fields: listOfMappedFields,
                    operator: "and"
                }
            },
            highlight: {
                fields: {
                    jobTitle: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    category: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    tags: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    jobDescription: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    headOffice: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    JobType: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    region: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                    applyLink: { "pre_tags": "", "post_tags": "" },
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Хотя бы подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать поиск по подстроке с нечётким поиском. То, что делаете Вы -- это поиск по всей строке. Конечно, тогда ничего не сматчится.

Comment: @hedgehogues спасибо за комент, попробую.

Comment: Почему Вы используйте phrase_prefix? насколько помню, он ищет по фразу с учетом порядка слов, используйте какой нибудь best_fields или most_fields